# msp430F1611 SPI communication

Tags: c, spi, msp430

I want to communicate the MSP430F1611 with any other controller (e.g Arduino ) or other MSP430F1611 using SPI communication, I visited this (gist.github.com/.../3326502) link and try to load this code but there is a problem,

These code line show errors,

```
 P1SEL = BIT1 + BIT2 + BIT4;
  P1SEL2 = BIT1 + BIT2 + BIT4;
  UCA0CTL1 = UCSWRST;                       // **Put state machine in reset**
  UCA0CTL0 |= UCMSB + UCSYNC;               // 3-pin, 8-bit SPI master
  UCA0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;                     // **Initialize USCI state machine**
  IE2 |= UCA0RXIE;
```

the errors is,

```
Error[Pe020]: identifier "P1SEL2" is undefined
Error[Pe020]: identifier "UCA0CTL1" is undefined 
Error[Pe020]: identifier "UCSWRST" is undefined 
Error[Pe020]: identifier "UCA0CTL0" is undefined 
Error[Pe020]: identifier "UCMSB" is undefined 
Error[Pe020]: identifier "UCSYNC" is undefined 
Error[Pe020]: identifier "UCA0RXIE" is undefined
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thank you

Regard.

Answer (score 1):

Those registers are not available in the MSP430F1611.
According to this [register definition header file](https://sourceforge.net/p/mspgcc/msp430mcu/ci/master/tree/upstream/msp430f1611.h), those do not exist. They are probably named different from the example you've copied.

See the family manual: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau049f/slau049f.pdf